# How to match a mongodb subarray based on main document id?

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have the following pipeline in my pymongo script:

```
pipeline = [
    {'$match': {'_id': '123456'}},
    {'$lookup': {
    'from': 'Case', 
    'localField': '_id', 
    'foreignField': 'RecordList.Record._id', 
    'as': 'CaseInfo'}
    },
   {'$unwind':'$CaseInfo'},
   {'$unwind':'$CaseInfo.RecordList'},
   {'$unwind':'$CaseInfo.RecordList.Record'},
   {'$match': {'CaseInfo.RecordList.Record._id': '123456'}}
]
```

I need to change the last line of code so that I don't need to specify the document id manually, but take it from the initial document.

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
{'$match': {'CaseInfo.RecordList.Record._id': '_id'}}
{'$match': {'CaseInfo.RecordList.Record._id': '$_id'}}
```

Could you please help me?

Also, is this the most efficient way to accomplish this, or should I be using $project? I tried using it, but I don't know the structure of the document and I need every field in the documents. I'm not sure if there's a way to not specify a "1" in the $filter operator (since I don't know the key names)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3.6 version, you can change the last line to

`{'$match': {$expr:{$eq:['$CaseInfo.RecordList.Record._id', '$_id']}}}`.

Alternatively you can rewrite the aggregation to use `$lookup` with pipeline variant.

Something like

```
[
  {"$match":{"_id":"123456"}},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"Case",
    "let":{"_id":"$_id"},
    "pipeline":[
      {"$unwind":"$RecordList"},
      {"$unwind":"$RecordList.Record"},
      {"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$RecordList.Record._id","$$_id"]}}}
    ],
    "as":"CaseInfo"
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$CaseInfo"}
]
```

Comment: I'm using 3.2, and I believe $expr was introduced in 3.6, so I'm not able to use it. Would you mind explaining how to change to 3.2?

Comment: You have to use `$project` to perform the comparison followed by `$match` but that will require you to list the other fields in the $project stage or you can use the `$redact` stage instead of $match stage in last line  like `{
  "$redact": {
    "$cond": [
      {
        "$eq": [
          "$CaseInfo.RecordList.Record._id",
          "$_id"
        ]
      },
      "$$KEEP",
      "$$PRUNE"
    ]
  }
}`